# Are my walls too thin to keep creepers from arming?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Some of my friends and I are building a wall to encompass the entirety of our house and farms, but creepers tend to explode and flood us with zombies in the night, because the walls are made of cobblestone fence (cobblestone wall). I am wondering if they are blowing up because cobblestone walls are slightly thinner than regular blocks (I believe they are still thick enough to prevent coming within 'arming' range of creepers, but I may be wrong), or is it because we are standing on top of the walls and the creepers jump up to us?

***Question:*** Can creepers get close enough to "arm" (start hissing), even if they are on the other side of Cobblestone Wall blocks? The reason this might be possible is because doors and glass panes are too thin, but cobblestone walls might be thick enough.

> W = CobbleStone Wall 
> I = Iron Bars 
> H = Wooden Doors 
> O = Log
>
> FRONT VIEW - DOOR SECTION
>
> I I I I I I I I I I I I I I I I I I I 
> O W W W O W H W O 
> O W W W O W H W O
>
> The walls are 2 Cobblestone Walls high, but then have Iron Bars on top of them. Note the door, there is a slight gap between the door and the wall, so creepers may be sensing us through this gap

Comment: Screenshot(s) please. (Walls *can* keep creepers from arming, so we need to see how you've constructed them to diagnose the problem.)

Comment: @Seven Unfortunately, I cannot get shots right now, but I will tonight. In the meantime, I'll do that thing with the things, you know?

Comment: Okay then: how tall is the wall at its lowest point?

Comment: @seven 2 CS walls high, with 1 iron bar each stack

Comment: I feel like I should just record some extensive research of my own, then link it. It would be easier than having to do it every time a new bit is needed.

Comment: I design mission-critical structures in Creative before using them in Survival for exactly this reason. A design failure in Creative is much easier to amend than in Survival!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Creepers can certainly get close enough to arm through cobblestone wall, but that's not the problem; they can even get close enough through a two-layer thick wall of obsidian; their arming range is a full three blocks. And yet, even a door is usually thick enough to stop them.

Creeper arming is not just based on distance, but also visibility. Cobblestone Walls are a block and a half tall for collision purposes, but not for Creeper line-of-sight. If the walls are only one layer tall, creepers have a clear line of sight over it and can still arm and fire.

Note that even transparent blocks like glass, glass panes, etc. block creepers' arming. And they can't see through the holes that form in Cobblestone walls more than one layer high; the blocks all still count as completely solid. However, the blocks *aren't* completely solid when they run up to most other blocks. So, while a glass wall,

[image: A glass wall]

a cobblestone wall,

[image: A cobblestone wall]

and doors

[image: A door]

are all fully able to stop them from arming, placing either glass or a door next to the walls gives them a gap to see you through:

[image: Gap between Cobble Wall and Glass]

[image: Gap between Cobble Wall and a Door]

Additionally, you can stop them from arming by getting much higher ground on them. If the top of their head is at least a full block below your feet, they won't arm.

Comment: Specific data you may want to add: creepers' arming radius is exactly 4 metres (Euclidean). (Derived from extensive testing done during the designing of a record farm.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie, is that the distance where they start to arm, or the minimum distance to stay armed? My own experience has been that their arming range is about two blocks.

Comment: So they can't arm through any block, even if it's as thin as a glass pane?

Comment: @TheUgly exactly. They just need to be solid-ish. So, not air, not water, not lava, not the empty half of slabs, not the gaps in stairs, etc.

Comment: If the glass pane is only connected to a row of cobblestone, it's possible that it only counts as a half-block, which they could be seeing over.  Or they could, as mobs can sometimes do, be jumping over your wall.

Comment: So the problem was that I was climbing on top of my wall, and giving them a line of sight. Thank you!

Comment: Can vines (which keep mobs from detecting you) also stop them? (Besides them just walking through)

Comment: I tested the "gaps between blocks" theory: gaps between the layers of cobble wall aren't a problem, but gaps between a door and a cobble wall *are* a problem. Gaps between cobble wall and glass panes are *also* bad.

Comment: @BillyMailman Yeah, I'm misremembering. To safe a captive creeper you need three intervening full blocks or four intervening fence/wall blocks. Less than three full blocks and they arm, so arming distance is <3 metres. (Heh, <3. Creepers really just want to be loved.)

Comment: Note also that a creeper will *not* arm if it is lower than one block below your feet. So a three-metre-high wall you can stand on and taunt creepers from, but with a two-metre wall they will see your taunt and raise you an explosion.